# timepicker does not display hour only lollipop version 5.1.0

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-5.0-lollipop, android-timepicker

[image]

I have implement android default time picker but runtime do not display hours please check below screen shot.

**XML file**

```
 <TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:timePickerMode="clock"
    android:headerBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
   />
```

**Java File**

```
TimePicker timePicker = findViewById(R.id.timePicker)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
   timePicker.setHour(this.hour);
   timePicker.setMinute(this.min);
}else{
   timePicker.setCurrentHour(this.hour);
   timePicker.setCurrentMinute(this.min);
}
```

Comment: Check layoutInspector the text color. Tools -> Android -> Layout Inspector

Comment: okay @deathangel908 i will check